How to cite in Korean?
Can I get some help on the correct way to cite a work in Korean? I am looking for the snippets:
page
pages
p.
pp.
cited on page 15
cited on pages 15, 17, 19
cit. on p. 15
cit. on pp. 15, 17, 19

and so far I have come up with these literal translations, that I am not sure are current usage in bibliography citation.
페이지
페이지
p.
pp.
인용 페이지 15
인용 페이지 15, 17, 19
인용 페이지 15
인용 페이지 15, 17, 19

Would someone, confirm this, correct it, or point me to the right direction or some work where I can see any material on this or examples?

Are you reading other papers in Korean too? How about just looking up how they do it, or referring to your paper's guidelines?

I am creating my own guidelines, I don't think there are any that have been written. If you know of any please point to them here, I'll be pleased to go after them and study each case and what is used. I would like to know of a repository of scientifc articles in Korean, but unfortutaley have not been able to locate any. Do you know of any?

sample references: https://www.dbpia.co.kr/journal/articleDetail?nodeId=NODE07407417, https://www.riss.kr/search/detail/ssoSkipDetailView.do?p_mat_type=1a0202e37d52c72d&control_no=c500e79d48c6855fffe0bdc3ef48d419

Fantastic set of examples. I see a low use of "page" designators which really make things clear and simple.
